# Crear variable de sesión php mediante onclick

Tags: php, html5

tengo un problema relacionado con las variables de sesión.
Necesito que tome el valor del vinculo que se pulsa:

```html
<!-- Submenu Paciente -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="MenuPatient" id="ginecologiaMenu" class="active">
<a href="#ginecologia" aria-controls="ginecologia" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = 'ginecologia'; ?>">Ginecología</a>
</li>
<li role="MenuPatient" id="obstetriciaMenu">
<a href="#obstetricia" aria-controls="obstetricia" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = 'obstetricia'; ?>">Obstetricia</a>
</li>
<li role="MenuPatient" id="antecedentesMenu">
<a href="#antecedentes" aria-controls="antecedentes" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="funcionAntecedentes() <?php $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = 'antecedentes'; ?>">Antecedentes</a>
</li>
<li role="MenuPatient" id="documentosMenu">
<a href="#documentos" aria-controls="documentos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="<?php $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = 'documentos';?>">Documentos</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Para así después poder usar esa variable de forma que cuando se vuelva a la página vuelva a la pestaña anterior dependiendo del valor de la variable.

El problema es que siempre toma el valor del último enlace: Documentos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que pretendes hacer, pero creo que estás un poco confundido mezclando variables de frontend con backend (php).

Comment: Solo quiero almacenar en una variable de sesión un valor u otro dependiendo de que opción del menú se seleccione.

Comment: Tienes varias opciones, desde pasar el parámetro por GET o utilizar un formulario POST con un campo hidden, o incluso Ajax, dependiendo como funcione tu aplicación web.

Comment: La idea sería que no recargara la página.

Comment: Entonces puedes hacer una solicitud ajax que activas con el clic, y pasas en parámetro por medio de un data-variable="valor", similar a lo que haces con data-toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno esta podría ser una solución posible, cambiar tu variable de session en la parte del backend, entonces tu codigo html quedaría mas o menos asi:

```
<!-- Submenu Paciente -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li role="MenuPatient" id="ginecologiaMenu" class="active">
      <a href="#ginecologia" aria-controls="ginecologia" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="modificarValor(1)">Ginecología</a>
   </li>
   <li role="MenuPatient" id="obstetriciaMenu">
       <a href="#obstetricia" aria-controls="obstetricia" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="modificarValor(2)">Obstetricia</a>
   </li>
   <li role="MenuPatient" id="antecedentesMenu">
       <a href="#antecedentes" aria-controls="antecedentes" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="modificarValor(3)">Antecedentes</a>
    </li>
    <li role="MenuPatient" id="documentosMenu">
       <a href="#documentos" aria-controls="documentos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="modificarValor(4)">Documentos</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

En la parte superior o en un archivo externo `js` colocar la siguiente función:

```
function modificarValor(valor){
   var url = 'server.php';
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     data: {valor},
     success:function(data){
        console.log("tu varible de sesion tiene el valor de "+ data);
     }
   });
}
```

Y en tu archivo `server.php` colocas lo siguiente, en donde solo se encargará de modificar tu variable de session dependiendo el valor que le pases.

```
$valor = $_POST['valor'];

session_start();

switch ($valor) {
    case 1:
        $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = "ginecologia";
        echo 'ginecologia';
        break;
    case 2:
        $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = "obstetricia";
        echo 'obstetricia';
    break;
    case 3:
        $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = "antecedentes";
        echo 'antecedentes';
    break; 
    case 4:
        $_SESSION['ListMenu'] = "documentos";
        echo 'documentos';
    break;
}
```

El codigo lo puedes mejorar mucho mas, esto es solo para que te des una idea de como lo puedes hacer. saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! He podido solucionar mi problema :)